# Unable to retrieve duplicate objects from JSON file

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read Json file with duplicate object but when I try to read it using java code it returns only last value instead of both. Please share the code so that I am able to store both objects.

My JSON format is:

```
"statements" : 
[
    {
      "kpCustomLevel" : 
       {
        "region" : "KNW",
        "statementType" : "Medical",
        "coverageType" : "DHMO"
        }
     }
 ]
"statements" : 
[
    {
       "kpCustomLevel" :
       {
        "region" : "KNP",
        "statementType" : "Medical1",
        "coverageType" : "DHMN"
        }
     }
]
```

I am trying to save result in Array so that I can use them in my code.

Comment: Since what you've included is not valid JSON by itself, _how_ are you reading it in your Java code? It's hard for anyone to say how to read invalid JSON - is it always invalid in this way? What happens if there are more than two objects?

Comment: `when I try to read it using java code` - what a code?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same key within the same object:

```
{
  "statements" : [ 
    { 
      "kpCustomLevel" : 
      { 
        "region" : "KNW", 
        "statementType" : "Medical", 
        "coverageType" : "DHMO" 
      } 
    }
  ], 
  "statements" : [ 
    { 
      "kpCustomLevel" : 
      { 
        "region" : "KNP", 
        "statementType" : "Medical1", 
        "coverageType" : "DHMN" 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

`"statements"` is the key that's duplicated. Keys within the same object of the schema shall be unique, reason why it's only getting the last one, what you could do is simply have a single `"statements"` key pointing to an array of objects (notice that even though the key appears in all of the objects, it is still unique per object) like this:

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "kpCustomLevel": {
        "region": "KNW",
        "statementType": "Medical",
        "coverageType": "DHMO"
      }
    },
    {
      "kpCustomLevel": {
        "region": "KNP",
        "statementType": "Medical1",
        "coverageType": "DHMN"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```